# Android Activity life cycle - onPause() and onResume()

Tags: android, activity-lifecycle

In the [Android developer diagram](http://developer.android.com/images/activity_lifecycle.png), I saw that `onResume()` is always called before `onPause()`. Assuming the user starts a new `Activity`, why should `onPause()` be preceded by `onResume()`?

I mean:

OnResume can be called in 2 occassions:

1) when user starting new activity (before OnPause)

2) when activity is in background and if the user brings the activity back to the
foreground

I expect in every case, something else should be done.

Answer (score 2):

You are getting it wrong. Whenever an activity is created, **onResume** is called just after **onStart**. Whenever your activity goes back stack **onPause** is called. Again if your activity comes back to foreground then **onResume** is called. So, it is not like, **onResume** is called before **onPause**. Whenever activity is returning from **onPause** state, **onResume** gets called instead of **onStart** or **onCreate**. This happens so that Android does not have to create Activity instance again and again though those instances are not properly destroyed. This is quite memory efficient too.

**NOTE:** If you app is running and the user presses **back** button or **home** button, then the Activity goes through **onPause()** and **onStop()** state. After this if the user is again coming back to your app then, **onRestart()**, **onStart()** and **onResume()** will be called sequentially.

**Then when the activity is only in *onPause()* state ?** When a **dialog** surfaces on top of your activity or your activity is **getting displayed in Split screen but it doesn't have focus (user is not interacting with your app)**. On these cases, activity goes to **onPause()** state only.

Answer (score 1):

> `onResume()` is always called before `onPause()`

This is correct. `onResume` is always called when the Activity is launched for the first time, before `onCreate`, and when the Activity is being resumed (user navigates back to your Activity)

> Assuming the user starts a new Activity, why should `onPause()` be
>   preceded by `onResume()`

`onPause` is only called when the Activity is put to background, or before `onDestroy` if the Application is being destroyed. So `onPause` is **always** being called **after** a call to `onResume` has been made. Why? Because that's the lifecycle of the Activity as defined by the Android framework.

Answer (score 0):

The life cycle of the activity is as follows

1. Fresh start via onCreate(), onStart(), onResume .... and close via onPause()->onStop()->onDestroy()
2. Yellow background: Activity goes into background and thus is no longer visible. The user returns back to the activity.
   e.g.

   - Switch off the phone screen while the activity is running: onPause()->onStop()
   - Switch on the screen again: onStart() -> onResume()
3. Green background: The activity stays in the visible screen area but is not active
   e.g. Activate multiple windows (split screen) occupying one part of the screen each and tip on your app to make it active

   - tip on the other app: onPause() is called in your app as it goes into pause but is still visible
   - tip on your app: onResume() is called

[image: activity life cycle]

Here is an example of a split screen with two apps:

[image: split screen with two apps]

see [android documentation on activity life cycle for details](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle)